# Error starting postgres "could not load server certificate file "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem": ee key too small"

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I am trying to start Postgres DB but it's failing. The log file /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log is showing the following line:

```
2023-12-04 13:01:32.197 UTC [22573] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem": ee key too small
2023-12-04 13:01:32.197 UTC [22573] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
```

I have tried to generate it again with:

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot write random bytes:
80B259F1827F0000:error:1200007A:random number generator:RAND_write_file:Not a regular 
file:crypto/rand/randfile.c:190:Filename=/dev/urandom
```

OpenSSL was updated from 1.1.1f to 3.0.8 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Updated from 3.0.8 7 to 1.1.1f? Surely there must be an error in that information. As a simple measure to get the server up, set `ssl = off` in `postgresql.conf`. Then you have time to deal with the certificates.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the opposite. I edited the question. From 1.1.1f to 3.0.8 7. With ssl = off works, but it isn't ideal.

Comment: Updated how?  Did you try replacing your distribution's OpenSSL libraries and binaries with v3.0.8 ones?  If so, you likely broke your OS.

Comment: Try to set the environment variable `RANDFILE` to `/tmp/randfile`, probably in `/etc/postgresql/*/*/environment`.